# Programming error in a basic python code

Tags: python

I am writing simple python code:

```
Question:
Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of
# strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first
# and last chars of the string are the same.
```

Solution I worked:

```
def match_ends(words):
    for items in words:
        count = 0
        los = len(items)
        first_char= items[0]
        last_char= items[los-1]
        if los >=2 and first_char is last_char:
            count = count+1
        else:
            count = count

    print count
    return

def main():
    print 'match_ends'
    match_ends(['aba', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb'])
```

I keep on Getting answer as 1 all the time, I think it is not looping entirely. Where is the error

Comment: I don't like the look of that `is`. Try using `==` instead. Oh, and move `count==0` outside of the loop.

Comment: Are you intending to reset `count` to `0` every iteration of the loop?

Comment: The `else: count=count` is useless.

Comment: Also a naked `return` at the end of a function

Comment: I think `count=count` was a desperate bid. :) I'll bet you, he will do it with all the answers here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another more concise way to do this is just:

```
sum(1 for s in words if len(s) > 1 and s[0] == s[-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `==` operator to compare the characters instead of the `is` keyword. Also you can use the `[-1]` index to slice from the back to get the last character instead of essentially doing `[len-1]`. You are also resetting the `count` to `0` at the beginning of each loop (also `count` is already a function name, try to avoid naming a variable with the same name)

That being said, here is the same idea with a few changes for readability and fixes for the above.

```
def matches(words):
    total = 0
    for word in words:
        if (len(word) > 1) and (word[0] == word[-1]):
            total += 1
    return total

>>> matches(['aba', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb'])
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you need to place count = 0 before the line `for items in words:`